# Where is the 'main' method of 'sourceSets' defined?

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I'm going through some simple Gradle examples, and trying to get my head around the syntax.  According to Gradle syntax, there must be a method called 'main' somewhere on 'sourceSets' (which is a SourceSetContainer) that takes a Closure.  I figured that I would be able to find it by browsing around the Gradle javadocs, but I can't find it.  Can someone point me to where 'main' is defined in this example?

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src']
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sourceSets` is a container of *named* source sets. The `java` plugin adds a source set named `main` (and another named `test`) to that container. As such, there is no physical method or property called `main`. `sourceSets.main { ... }` could also be written as `sourceSets.getByName("main") { ... }`.

Comment: Thanks!  That pointed me in the right direction.  I looked up the documentation for NamedDomainObjectCollection (which SourceSetContainer inherits).  The root of my confusion was that I was unaware that methods could be added to an object dynamically, but the documentation for [NamedDomainObjectCollection](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/NamedDomainObjectCollection.html) says otherwise.